# Static vector of shared_ptr's for all the objects of a class hierachy

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, shared-ptr, static-members

I have a small class hierachy and I want all the objects to have a pointer to any other object from this class hierachy. So I decided a `static vector` of `shared_ptr` a good idea. More specifically, I have a class `A` which has a `protected` field:

```
static std::vector< std::shared_ptr<A> > vector_of_objects;
```

It also has this line in the constructor to fill the vector:

```
vector_of_objects.emplace_back( this );
```

Hence the gist of the idea: when creating an object of any class inherited from `A`, it would call the base class constructor and put a pointer to itself to the static vector.

Frankly, I am puzzled whether this is even possible . Anyway, at this line in contructor I'm getting a linking error - undefined reference to `A::vector_of_objects`. Do I need to preinitialize the vector somehow?..

In case I'm getting this wrong, is there any way to implement the idea except creating an external vector?

Comment: Is the vector a global variable or a class member variable of A?

Comment: The vector is a `static` member of the class `A`.

Comment: if it's a vector of shared pointers then you're looking at either a ton of dangling references (when an object comes off the stack) or the objects will all survive for the lifetime of the program since their shared_ptrs last forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need such a structure, so far I have the impression that you just need a set (not std::set) of objects. As for the linkage error you should define your static member like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> A::vector_of_objects;
```

Otherwise you just have declared it, not defined.

Updating with a full snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
    public:
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> allObjects;

    A() {
        allObjects.emplace_back(this);
    }
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> A::allObjects;
```

Comment: I've got an `extra qualification A::` error... Could you please clarify your answer? I don't really understand why do I need this `A::` for a class member definition.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry, I did get you wrong. It seems to be because of my misunderstading of `static`, as well as the all the trouble in general. But still, when I did this according to the msdn link, I've got a linking error of `multiple definition of A::vector_of_objects`, meanwhile without the declaration I'm still getting `undefined reference to A::vector_of_objects`. I really don't get it.

Comment: I added the complete excerpt of code that should compile.

Comment: Kaz, the definition does not belong in the header (which is why I think you get the multiple definitions).

Comment: Note that this alone is has the potential to cause a SEGFAULT when the `allObjects` vector is cleaned up when the program terminates, if you don't construct your A instances dynamically.

Comment: Peter, yes, you are right. I think that was the problem because the code was compilled without any errors when I moved the definition to cpp. But when I executed the program it brought an invalid pointer error after it had terminated - which brings me to AtlasC1 warning. And it worked smoothly when I constructed an object dynamically. But I can't really see, what's wrong with not consrtucting it dynamically?

Comment: @kazarey Because the `shared_ptr` will still try to `delete` the object even if it wasn't constructed via `new`. Also if you do `shared_ptr<A>(new A)` then you'll have two separare `shared_ptr`s which don't know about each other, and you'll have dangling pointers and double-`delete`s. Therefore `A` should inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Answer (score 2):

A `static` data-member must not only be declared in the class-definition, but also defined in exactly one translation-unit, if ODR used.

As a side-note, your static vector should only store `weak_ptr`s, unless you really want to keep them all alive like forever (in which case raw pointers would be sufficient anyway).

Also, take a look at `std::enable_shared_from_this` for your base-class, if they really all shall be `shared_ptr`-managed.